# second click on input type button jquery

Tags: jquery

I have below code and i want to have default input type button when second clicked

```
        $(function () {
            $('.inputbutton').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).css("background-color", "gray");                    
            });
        });
```

Comment: What you mean by second clicked?

Comment: when i click the button css changes it is working but when i click second time i want to remove css change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you just want to remove the inline CSS you add when clicked?

Why don't you toggle a class on the button and style via external Stylesheet?

```
$(function () {
    $('.inputbutton').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('is-highlighted');
    });
});
```

In you CSS of course you would have to style the class accordingly

```
.is-highlighted {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

If you really want to stick with your "inline styles added via javascript" solution, just check if the style attribute is set and if so, remove it using [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

In my opinion styles belong in a stylesheet and not in a javascript file. (Of course there are exceptions to this rule)